# google appengine- aptana studio

Tags: google-app-engine, pydev, aptana3

I am trying to use aptana studio (pydev) for google appengine project.
I am having problem with configuring appengine.
How do I find google appengine directory ON MAC

Answer (score 1):

Try: `/usr/local/bin/`

As in: `/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py`